# Is Enterprise Value basically all the money that's been borrowed?

Tags: enterprise

I trying to learn some basic finance and I had difficulty understanding the concept of Enterprise Value. Specifically, I saw this equation:

> EV = Market Capitalization + Market Value of Debt – Cash and
>   Equivalents

I am confused by the fact that having Cash and Cash Equivalents actually brings down the Enterprise Value, while "borrowed money" like debt and shares issued to lenders (which increases market capitalization) increases the Enterprise Value?

I grew up thinking having more cash and cash equivalent is what makes your business more valuable?  But is that supposed to be different once you reach big business/enterprise level business?  Once you're big business, the value of your company depends on how much money you can borrow?  And actually having cash on hand is bad for the business? I am very confused...

So does this mean Enterprise Value is the value of what the business owes?  Why don't they call it Enterprise Owing Value instead (or something like that)

Comment: where did you see the equation?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/valuation/ebitda-multiple/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cash is removed because it's incorporated (theoretically) in the market capitalization, and can easily be removed from the company without any immediate impact to the "intrinsic" business value.

One interpretation of Enterprise Value is "how much would it cost to recreate this business if the owners took out all of the cash".  You'd have to borrow money (or sell equity) in order to purchase the equivalent assets.

Think about it this way - if you had a company that only owned a delivery truck worth $1,000, had no other assets (other than cash) and no debt, but had $1 Million in cash, the company would be "worth" $1 Million (plus the value of the truck), but it would only take $1,000 to buy the truck and you'd have replicated the business perfectly. So the value of the "enterprise" is only $1,000. If you wanted to sell the company to someone, you'd either keep the cash and sell the "enterprise" or include the cash in the purchase price, which would be a net wash.

Comment: Hmm..so it's kind of like there's some value to a business that goes beyond cash...like a business' reputation, it's relationships with customers, it's R&D efforts etc...the value of these things are harder to measure.  People buy shares from an enterprise and firms lend money to an enterprise because they are investing in some future value.  And this investment is the Enterprise Value and is some how reflective of it's future value?  Any immediate cash on hand, as you said, would just be a net-wash if you try to sell the enterprise

Comment: @John Well that's true but more important in reality, the value is in its assets that produce income going forward. Cash does not produce income in itself - it's used to buy assets (or operate activities) that _do_ produce income.

Answer (score 1):

“Enterprise value” is the value of a business, not the value of the company.

If a company has 100 million dollars in the bank, that is nice for the company, and it makes the company more valuable, but it doesn’t affect the business - the business has the same value, whether the bank account is plus 100 million, or whether it is zero, or whether there is 100 million debt.

Look at it the other way round and it makes more sense: Take three companies with the same annual revenue, same annual profit, same outlook for the future, so the businesses have the same value. That would be the enterprise value. Now you add their cash and subtract the debt, and you get the market caps.

I’ll give you an extreme example: A company owns 1,000 stores, each worth a million dollars. No cash or debt. The company has market caps = enterprise value = 1 billion. The company sells 999 stores. Market caps is unchanged, but the business is worth one million only, so enterprise value = 1 million.